# intermittent washed-out colors when booting Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, colors

Sometimes when I boot Ubuntu 22.04, the colors are washed out and distorted, print is unreadable, and graphics are unstable. Sometimes it boots to a black screen. Other times it boots just fine. Sometimes it boots properly after one restart, but sometimes it takes as long as an hour to boot properly. I have 20.04 on a thumb drive, and that always boots properly, so it seems to be the OS and not the computer. I have tried going into recovery mode and fixing packages, updating grub, etc., but none of that seems to make a difference. I have also tried going into the boot menu and checking off a box that, while I can't remember the exact wording, says something like "revert to original settings.

My computer is a Zareason desktop hardware model Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450M DS3H) with AMD® Ryzen 3 2200g with radeon vega graphics × 4 processor and NVAB graphics.

I am currently simply not turning the computer off or restarting unless I have to. I would appreciate a more elegant solution to this problem. Thank you!